# Find memory leaks in a test-session

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pytest

I have a sneaking suspicion that I have a memory leak somewhere in an application. It is absolutely evident with the test-runner. When I run all unit-tests, I notice a *considerable* slow-down the more tests are running.

But I have absolutely *no* clue where to start looking. I found "[muppy](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/muppy.html)" but I don't quite see how to use it and how to integrate it with pytest.

I first want to locate the problem. It *might* be in the unit-tests themselves, or in the application code. If it's in the application code it would be absolutely critical to find and fix it. If it's in the unit-tests it would be less critical.

Is there only "muppy"? And if yes, how do I run it with pytest?

Comment: have you tried builtin tracemalloc lib?

Comment: Not yet. I've came across it via muppy, but just like with muppy, I am a bit lost as to *how* to use it. I could maybe take snapshots on each unit-test `tearDown` call and write them out somewhere, but the output is still a bit foreign to me. First time that I have to deal with something like that ;) The thing is, most examples target one specific function (the one leaking memory). My problem is that I don't know which one it is.